# Merge review and flag history into the timeline tool

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

There is a relatively new moderator-only timeline view for posts. It shows edits, comments, close votes, when a post was put into a review queue and most other events that happened to that post. What it doesn't show are certain types of flags like the "recommend closure" flags and comment flags. There are two other reports for that, the post flag history and the post review history.

There is also a lot of redundancy between those three tools, the flag history doesn't only contain flags but also a lot of other stuff that is also visible in the timeline.

The new timeline is the better UI, it has pretty colors and rounded borders and stuff. Apart from being prettier, it has a few more nice features and is easier to read in my opinion.

I don't see any reason for the review and flag history to exist in separate reports, any information in them that isn't already in the timeline should be added there and the additional reports removed entirely. Splitting the information makes certain tasks much more annoying that they need to be. For example, to find out why a certain post was put into a review queue, the timeline is not enough because it doesn't contain the flags which can put a question into the review queues.

What would be very useful in the timeline view, especially if the information from the flag and review histories is added, would be a way to filter the timeline. Just a few buttons that would show or hide specific categories like flags, comments or review events.

Comment: We see review tasks and flags in the mod timeline on Stack Overflow. Does it not show up on other sites? Or is there some other information missing that should be added to the timeline?

Comment: @animuson I don't see flags in `admin/posts/timeline`, only in `admin/posts/[post-id]/show-flags`. Review tasks are in the timeline, the review history seems mostly redundant, though I'm not sure if there is additional information in there in some situations.

Comment: Oh, are they *recommend closure* flags? I forgot those don't show up in the timeline. All other flags should, though.

Comment: @animuson Hmm, looks like I got a bit unlucky with the examples I used and every single one I tried had only "recommend closure" flags. Other flags appear in the timeline.